# Inputting a function on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have been trying to write a MATLAB code that can take in any function for optimization with as many variables as the user wants.

```
function Enter_Optimization_Code

clear all
clc

x=[];
U='';

n=input('Enter the number of variables= ')
U=input('Enter function with variables as x(1), x(2), x(3)..= ','s')
start=input('Enter coordinates of the starting point as [1,3,..]= ')

for i=1:n
    x(i)=start(i)
end

int(U)
```

The code is asking the user to enter the number of variables they want and then the function they want to optimize (I didnt write the optimization code yet). For now, I want the code to plug in the value of the starting point into the function and spit out the answer.

e.g. I am entering a function that is x(1)+x(2) and start point as [1,2]. This should cause the code to do the calculation of 1+2=3 and print 3. This is what's happening instead:

```
Enter the number of variables= 2

n =

     2

Enter function with variables as x(1), x(2), x(3)..= x(1)+x(2)

U =

x(1)+x(2)

Enter coordinates of the starting point as [1,3,..]= [1,2]

start =

     1     2


x =

     1


x =

     1     2

Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in Enter_Optimization_Code (line 17)
```

Can anybody solve this?

Comment: Using `input` is a poor choice for getting functions, you're much better off to have these things inputted as arguments to the function: `function Enter_Optimization_Code(x,U)`

Comment: My intention is to let the user use any function like x(1)+x(2) or x(1)-x(2)^x(3)

Comment: To address the question: the error is pretty clear - in your code `int` is not defined. So define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to integrate the function with the symbolic function [`int`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int.html), you can't pass a string input to that function, it has to be a symbolic expression, check the documentation.

You probably need to do `int(sym(U))` instead to convert the string `U` into a symbolic expression.

**EDIT based on comments and using TroyHaskin's suggestion**

Here's a version that should work. However, I'm not sure why this is a function, it should really be a script.

```
function Enter_Optimization_Code
% Not sure why you're using a function, this should really be a script

% clear all should only be used in scripts, not in functions
clc

% n=input('Enter the number of variables= '); not needed
U=input('Enter function with variables as x(1), x(2), x(3)..= ','s');
start=input('Enter coordinates of the starting point as [1,3,..]= ');

f = str2func(['@(x)',U]);
y = feval(f,start);

disp([U 'evaluated at x=([' num2str(start) ']) = ' num2str(y)])
```

Comment: So what do you add to print out U? Print U gives me int(x(1), x) for a function U=x(1) at [1]

Comment: As you've already been told, that's not what `print` is for. Again check the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html). Use `disp(U)` if you want to display `U`, but the whole code and question doesn't really make any sense to me.

Comment: I see. So let me clarify. The code will take in any U(x) like x(1)+x(2) and the corresponding values of x(1) and x(2) to spit an answer. Let's just use U(x)=x(1)+x(2) as an examples. The first question asks how many variables there and the input is 2 (x(1) and x(2)).

Comment: The second input asks for the function (here its x(1)+x(2)). This expression will be stored as a string. The third input asks for the values of the variables (e.g. [1,3]. This would mean x(1)=1 and x(2)=3). The code takes the expression stored as a string and convert it to function x(1)+x(2) and input the values [1,3] and solve it. x(1)+x(2)=1+3=4. So the code should print the value 4.

Comment: Ok. Well that's not what your code is doing at all... I'll edit my answer later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to enter the equation in this manner, you can convert the string to an anonymous function using [`str2func`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
fun = str2func(['@(x)',U]);
```

This will work for function literals like `x(1)-x(2)^x(3)` and valid function calls `my_opt(x)`.

Comment: How do I print the value of U? `print U` fails

Comment: `print` is a function to literally print a figure or save it to a file. If you want to see the function handle, use `disp(fun);`.  To retrieve a value from the handle, use it as any normal function call: `val = fun(1);`.